# Enveloping, signing and creating PKCS#7 DER message with .pfx certificate

Tags: c#, ssl-certificate, digital-signature, certificate, pkcs#7

My task is to create data that are digitally signed in format of `PKCS#7 version 1.5 (RFC 2315) DER (ITU-T Recommendation X.690)` - basically `ANSI.1` with `X.509 signature`?

the message must satisfy following:

- must be type `signedData`
- must contain signed data
- must contain signer's certificate
- must contain one digital signature

My code is following

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    string pfx = @"C:\Users\marek\Downloads\mfcr\marek-pfx.pfx";
    string xml = @"C:\Users\marek\Downloads\mfcr\souhr20141.xml";
    X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(pfx, "thepass");

    byte[] publicBytes = cert.RawData;

    //var f = new FileStream(xml, System.IO.FileMode.Open);
    var fileContent = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(xml);

    char[] cArray = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(fileContent).ToCharArray();
    RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)cert.PrivateKey;

    byte[] signedData = rsa.SignData(new System.Text.UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(cArray), new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider());

    RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa2 = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)new X509Certificate2(publicBytes).PublicKey.Key;

    var dataGenerator = new CmsEnvelopedDataStreamGenerator();
    bool verified = rsa2.VerifyData(new System.Text.UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(cArray), new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider(), signedData);

    File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\Users\marek\Downloads\mfcr\Foo.p7b", signedData);
 }
```

The `WebService` that Iam sending the `Foo.p7b` responds with: File is not in expected format of PKCS7(DER).

This code for sending the `HttpWebRequest` :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {

            string fileName = (@"C:\Users\marek\Downloads\mfcr\Foo.p7b");
            WebResponse rsp = null;
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("https://adisepo.mfcr.cz/adistc/epo_podani");
            request.ClientCertificates.Add(new X509Certificate(pfx,"thepass"));
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = "application/pkcs7-signature";
            request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
            var encoder = new UTF8Encoding();
            var reqStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream());
            // Write the XML text into the stream
            writer.WriteLine(GetTextFromXMLFile(fileName));
            writer.Close();
            reqStream.Close();
            rsp = request.GetResponse();
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(rsp.GetResponseStream());
            string result = sr.ReadToEnd();
            sr.Close();
            Console.Write("\n příkaz odeslán  \n");
            Console.Write(result);
            Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Read();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }
    private static string GetTextFromXMLFile(string file)
    {
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(file);
        string ret = reader.ReadToEnd();
        reader.Close();
        return ret;
    }
}
```

I'm struggling with this issue for almost 5 days - I'm surely not expert on digital signature or certificates.

From what I learned so far - to create message like that I should do:

1. Sign the `xml` with my `private key`
2. Envelope that blob with my `public key`

But how could the recipient check whether I am the real sender? Should I add to `HttpWebRequest` parameter with my certificate? Or that step 2 - Enveloping the message is enough for him to check that?

Thank you everyone for your time and replies.

Comment: @OndrejSvejdar it is - I tried but still getting same response from the `WebService`. Thanks anyway, I edited my code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your code tries digitally sign byte representation of XML, but signing XML requires more processing before signing. For example XML requires to be canonicalized (or signed message can be injected with unsigned data), and there is a special format for enveloped signatures. I don't know what is actual method Danovy Portal uses, but if it uses standard way, you can follow the links below and sign your data.

[MSDN: How to: Sign XML Documents with Digital Signatures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229745%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

[How enveloped signatures look](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms767623%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

And just for information (don't think you really need to read this)
[W3C Xml Signature specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-core/)

EDIT: to send pkcs#7 message change the code. When generating

```
        ContentInfo contentInfo = new ContentInfo(new System.Text.UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(cArray));
        SignedCms cms = new SignedCms (contentInfo);
        CmsSigner signer = new CmsSigner (cert);
        cms.ComputeSignature (signer);
        byte[] pkcs7=cms.Encode ();
        File.WriteAllBytes(@"../../Foo.p7b", pkcs7);
```

When send:

```
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("https://adisepo.mfcr.cz/adistc/epo_podani");
            //we don't need to add certificate to POST
    //      request.ClientCertificates.Add(new X509Certificate(pfx,"test"));
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = "application/pkcs7-signature";
            request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
            var encoder = new UTF8Encoding();
            using (var reqStream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                // Write pkcs#7 into the stream
                byte[] pkcs = File.ReadAllBytes(@"../../Foo.p7b");
                reqStream.Write(pkcs, 0, pkcs.Length);
            }
            rsp = request.GetResponse();
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, what I'm supposed to do is PKCS#7 message (or object) that will be send to WebService - I believe signed xml is something different, isnt't it?

Comment: You send to service digitalSignature of binary representation of your XML and certificate. You do not send XML data. If service requires signed data, you have to sent data, signature and certificate. XmlSignature holds all of these things in one object but it differs from PKCS#7 format. If service requires PKCS#7 format, than you should create PKCS#7 message and send it. You can use SignedCms class to do it. If service requires encryption of the message then you also need server public key to do it.

Comment: Yes the PKCS#7 format is the way I need it. May you please help me with the code? Explain what Iam doing wrong? Thanks alot.

Comment: I added example of code. Tried it with service, it responds other message (podpis je platny). Don't know the chech, maybe it asks me to buy signature?

Comment: Nah, hehe, it says that the signature is valid. may I know what class should I use for ContentInfo, SignedCms, CmsSigner please? Is it BouncyCastle or `System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs` ? Somehow Iam not able to access System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs.

Comment: Yes, it is the "System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54928/discussion-between-marek-and-user128048).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at BouncyCastle - it has all you need for that:

http://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/

Comment: I guess this one was meant as a comment - I already tried `BouncyCastle` but unfortunately I wasn't able to find any particular example for my issue. May you please provide some code example how to achieve that? Thanks so much.